# FileOutputStream get stucked while writing

Tags: android, video, buffer, streamwriter, fileoutputstream

```
File file = new File(appfolderpath + "test.mp4");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileOutputStream.write(videoconnectionresponse.bodyAsBytes());
fileOutputStream.close();
Log.i("DOWNLOAD", "FINISHED");
```

videoconnectionresponse is given by `Jsoup.connect(videoUrl).ignoreContentType(true).execute();`

If I download images this way there aren't any problems, it seems.
But with videos things are different, and so far I tried with only two videos:

-one with a length of 30s; everytime I download it and try to play, the player blocks at around 20 seconds saying that it's impossible to reproduce it.

-another with a length of 1min; well, this get blocked at 7 seconds..

Can someone explain me why I have this trouble?

### UP

Comment: Are you complaining about write() of file output stream or a videop player that wont play . Pretty unclear where this is about.

Comment: Do not give length in seconds. Better would be file size.

Comment: @greenapps I am writing a bytearray to a `FileOutputStream`

Comment: @greenapps the problem, basically, is that not all bytes get written, as it seems

Comment: Give the length of that video file in bytes if you want help. Why has this to be asked twice? And explain what this has to do with a player.

Comment: @greenapps the fact is that I can't give you a length just because it isn't always the same video! The URL passed in the Jsoup.connect() method is chosen by me in the EditText, in it will always point an mp4; then I want to download and store it, as well as normal downloads you do in browsers, to play it whenever I want with the video player

Comment: As you refuse to give lengths and further just post irrelevant info im unable to help you.

Comment: @greenapps `Log.i("LENGTH STREAM", String.valueOf(videoconnectionresponse.bodyAsBytes().length));` and after the write `Log.i("LENTH FILE", String.valueOf((int)file.length()));` gives I/LENGTH STREAM: `1048576` and `I/LENTH FILE: 1048576` so the bytes length is equal; also, I opened the video, and it is 41 seconds, as it should be, but only the first 9 seconds are reproducible (I don't know how to see the byte length of this); are this information enough? Where's the problem?

Comment: So you receive 1048576 bytes and the saved file is 104576 bytes. But how many bytes were send? And how is it possible that videoconnectionresponse is not a bytearray itself? What was it? You are not showing receive code. And did not explain why you would use jsoup to receive a file.

Comment: @greenapps I've already explained what is videoconnectionresponse: is given by Jsoup.connect(videoUrl).ignoreContentType(true).execute(); the url is like "http://website.com/something.mp4" and the variable is not an bytearray itself because in that way I only receive a Response, which after I parse in bytearray;  there's not a precise reason of why I am using jsoup: I was already using it (for other things), then I decided to use it to get bytearray of the video